# Invalid charsets in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, character-encoding

i'm using mysql. When im doing simple query `SELECT * FROM table` It returns  РђР»РµРєСЃРµРµРІРёС‡. It should display russian letters. My database, table, columns are set utf8_general_ci. The php files are utf8 without bom. When i query set NAMES cp1251, it solve the problems, but why there is cp1251, if all things are in utf 8?

Database connection

```
class Database { 

    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = '';

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }
    function connect() {
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=university;charset=utf8', $this->user, $this->password);
            $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
    }

    function selectQuery( $sql ) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    function insertQuery( $sql ) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Query

```
$this->db = new Database();
$q = $this->db->selectQuery('SELECT * FROM students');
$data = $this->db->stmt->fetchAll($q);
```

Comment: I'm glad you've changed to PDO after your last question :)

Comment: -1 for asking the same question twice

Answer (score -1):

Use this queries after your connection for set the collations manual.

```
$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost; dbname = dbname', $username, $pswd);
$PDO -> exec("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_persian_ci';");
$PDO -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");
$PDO -> exec("set names utf8");
```

I set this lines for Persian, you have to set second line `utf8_persian_ci` for your language...
I had same problem with Persian and this helped me, Hope to be helpful for you too...

Comment: @user3005741 I had forgotten to write last line which is must important part of the code... $PDO-> exec("set names utf8");
sorry for that, now try this...